# Sorting millions of int/string pairs using Java

Tags: java, sorting

I have 50,000,000 (integer, string) pairs in a text file. The integers are times in milliseconds, so are 13 digits long (e.g. 1337698339089).

The entries in the text file are like this:

```
1337698339089|blaasdasd
1337698339089|asdasdas
1337698338089|kasda
```

There can be identical entries.

I want to sort the entries on the integers (in ascending order) preserving any duplicate integers and preserving the (integer, string) pairs. The approach I have taken is leading to  memory errors, and so I'm looking for alternative approaches.

My approach is something like this (using some pseudo-code):

```
// declare TreeMap to do the sorting
TreeMap<Double, String> sorted = new TreeMap<Double, String>();

// loop through entries in text file, and put each in the treemap:
for each entry (integer, string) in the text file:

   Random rand = new Random();
   double inc = 0.0;

   while (sorted.get(integer + inc) != null) {
       inc = rand.nextDouble();
   }

   sorted.put(integer + inc, string);
```

I am using random numbers here to ensure that duplicate integers can be entered in the treemap (by incrementing them by a double between 0 and 1).

```
// to print the sorted entries:
for (Double d : sorted.KeySet()) {
    System.out.println(Math.round(d) + "|" + sorted.get(d));
}
```

This approach works but breaks down for 50,000,000 entries (I think because the treemap is becoming too large; or possibly because the while loop is running for too long).

I would like to know what approach more experienced programmers would take.

Many thanks!

Comment: Homework? Why not just use built in java methods. Or semi-copy them. They're quite optimized.

Comment: I'd just fill a vector/arraylist and then sort it out

Comment: @BigMike have you tried to store 50 millions of data in an arraylist without getting `OutOfMemoryException`?

Comment: Don't use java for this. `sort -n` is your friend.

Comment: "The approach I have taken is leading to memory errors" - and what are the exact errors?

Comment: Is it mandatory to use java? Using a database and sql for that might be a better idea.

Comment: Did you try to use time : linenumber pairs? You wont need the strings until you write the result. You just need to read the file two times.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza 50 millions is not that much memory, we're talking about very simple datas, well, it's java, so probably it'll be slow, then you're right.

Comment: @Andrew Is this a one time operation? does it need to happen daily? Hourly? As data is added? A single run is going to be treated differently than something that needs to happen on a schedule.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a list, if you have enough memory. I would create a separate class for the entry:

```
class Foo : Comparable<Foo> {
    private final long time;
    private final String text;

    // Constructor etc
}
```

In terms of memory, you need to be able to store 50 million instances, and references to them. On a 32-bit JVM, that would be:

- 8 bytes of overhead per object (IIRC)
- 8 bytes for the `time`
- 4 bytes for the `text` field
- ~54 bytes for the string (8 byte overhead + three `int` fields IIRC + `char[]` array reference + ~32 bytes for a 10 character array)
- 4 bytes for the reference in the array or `ArrayList`

So that's about 80 bytes per instance - say 100 to round up. To store 50,000,000 of those would take 5,000,000,000 bytes, aka 5GB, which is more than I believe a 32-bit JVM will cope with.

So to do all this in memory, you'll need a 64-bit machine and 64-bit JVM, and then the overhead potentially increases somewhat due to larger references etc. Feasible, but not terribly pleasant.

A large part of this is due to the strings, however. If you really wanted to be efficient, you *could* create a giant char array, then store offsets into it within `Foo`. Read into the array as you read the text data, and then use it to write out the data after sorting. More complex, and ugly, but considerably more memory-efficient.

Alternatively, you could do this *not* all in memory - I'm sure if you search around you'll find lots of information about sorting via the file system.

Comment: Jon, excuse me, how c# behaves in a similar scenario ? How much memory will it use ?

Comment: @BigMike: The .NET string implementation would only use one object rather than two, which would reduce the overhead a bit. Additionally, using a custom value type you could potentially avoid a fair amount of per object overhead for `Foo` - at the cost of making it more expensive to copy values of type `Foo`. The general principle would be the same, but it's possible that with the reduced overhead you might be able to fit the 50 million entries into memory.

Comment: thanks for clarification, yet I do suspect that .NET is a little more friendly on 64 bit OS than JVM.

Comment: @JonSkeet - thanks. I'm going to try this approach... I don't fully understand the char array suggestion. What I may do is allocate an index number to each string, and store these in a text file, so I can replace the strings with integers. It will be a little while until I'm able to implement your suggestions - will get back when I've tried.

Comment: @Andrew based on this answer and [this post on internet](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-sort-a-million-32-bit-integers) I would split the first file in 2 or 4 files (maybe more, that depends on you) and apply MergeSort for every file, after that I would apply MergeSort again to mix the data from the files into 1 file having all the data sorted.

Comment: @Andrew: Yes, replacing the strings with index numbers will certainly help - the only problem would then be loading the "just strings" part later :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Is the goal to sort by string? If so, how often are the strings repeated? Not terribly familiar with java, but maybe make it "String, List<Long>" instead? If the strings repeat enough, maybe the memory footprint would be small enough to fit into a 32 JVM?

Comment: @WernerCD: No, the goal is to sort by integer.

Comment: @JonSkeet At that point... if needed, why not do a breakout into time-ranges... say by month, quarter or year... parse the big file into separate files that can be individually sorted and recombined: "Foreach line in file => Extract date => println into (yyyymm.txt, yyyyQ#, etc) ... sort each file and append to sorted.txt".

Comment: +1 You could use a `char[]` or `byte[]` instead of a `String` to reduce memory consumption. You could also add the data structures to a List instead of a Map and sort the list.

Comment: @BigMike I would love to hear more. c.f. the JVM will use 32-bit references for heap sizes of up to 32 GB. What optimisations does .NET have specific to 64-bit runtime?

Comment: @WernerCD: If you know the time range, that makes sense, yes. If you don't, it's not so easy.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Yes, I was definitely suggesting using a list rather than a map. I don't think a map is the right approach at all here. I don't think the 64-bit CLR has anything like compressed OOPs, unfortunately.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I was thinking about object size overhead and extensive memory access, but it's just a feeling of mine. .NET framework on Windows IMHO interacts with HW resources with a little bit of easyness, compared to JVM. But it's just a feeling. (I'm still  a noob with C#)

Comment: IMHO, .NET uses windows functionality and services more naturally.

Answer (score 2):

I might consider using a database (like H2; which is convenient since you can pull it right into your Java project) and setup the index the way you want it. Databases have already solved the problem of dealing with a lot of data and organizing it. Then you can do a SQL query to get the results in order and write them back out.

The result set will stream the data out to you in chunks; not try to load everything into a single list.

While H2 does support in memory; I would configure it to use a disk in this case unless you have a lot of RAM and 64bit Java.

Comment: +1 for a great practical solution. H2 is a good fit for these types of tasks.

Comment: I think you will find H2 does not work well with 50 million records.  I have found sqlite to scale better than H2 (https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc)

Answer (score 1):

Why use a `double` to store a `long`?

A `Map<Long, String>` cannot have duplicate keys.  One will overwrite the other.

I doubt that you can fit all this into memory.  That's 0.5 GB just for storing the longs, more for the Strings.  You probably can't do it with 32 bit JVM.

Answer (score 1):

Did you give the JVM more memory?  Try running it with a -Xmx1024M command line option.  And the treeMap seems needlessly complicated, you can use the built-in Java commands

Answer (score 1):

Your issue looks to be of 2 parts:

1. **The Algorithm:** I would recommend using some of the build in java sorting algorithms. Easy to find references on google, such as [this](http://www.digizol.com/2008/07/java-sorting-comparator-vs-comparable.html).
2. **The JVM:** The root of your issue sounds like you might not have enough memory allocated to your java virtual machine. I would recommend increasing the max size, since you are dealing with a descent amount of information.

The JVM args you are looking for should be:

- **-Xms** specifies the initial Java heap size and
- **-Xmx** the maximum Java heap size.

Reference: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0131.html

Answer (score 0):

What was the error thrown? Can you successfully load all the data into memory?
I suggest you try the Java Comparator class. Maybe I will try something like creating a custom object to represent the pair:

```
class Entry{
    long i;
    String s;
}
```

Then create a custom Comparator

```
class IComp implements Comparator<Entry>{
    public int compare(Entry e1, Entry e2){
      if(e1.i < e2.i) return -1;
      //complete the rest

    }
}
```

Then put all objects into an array Entry[] entry, and create a comparator IComp icomp
Use Arrays.sort(entry, icomp)

As you will be creating 50 million objects you need to ensure there's enough heapspace.

If you have a large number of duplicate Strings, and if these Strings are immutable; you may create a Set to store the Strings, and recycle them to create lighter weight objects in your Entry

Entry.s = set.get()...

Answer (score 0):

I would love to solve this by sorting chunks of data and write them into different files and applying a merge sort on those files.. Here's  [working demo](http://www.codeodor.com/index.cfm/2007/5/14/Re-Sorting-really-BIG-files---the-Java-source-code/1208), which might helpful for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are going to use all the of the values when you are done sorting. But the number 50million gives me a hint that it's possible you're just going to take the top X values after the sort and do something with them.

In that case: Just make use a min heap, every time you encounter a number that is larger than the top of the heap, remove the min from the heap and add the new number. This way you do not have to keep all the numbers in memory, only X of them.